# accessing values from SQL database for xml namespace tags in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, xml

Hi. I have written a java code to create xml tags in separate xml file(.xml) and query the database. My xml tag is in this format:

```
<company comp:loc=" "/>
```

Now I need to get values for blank field (loc=" ") from SQL database.

How to get these values from SQL database for xml tag in java?

Comment: Database structure will be helpful. The answer depends on what exactly " " means in your system - is it your version of NullObject?

Comment: `field(" ")` looks like a space to me.

Comment: "" means not null... its a field shoud be filled with values accessed from database.. ex:- <company comp:loc="mumbai"/>... mumbai is a value shoud be accessed from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        ResultSet rs;
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Connected to server OELDBSQL!!!");
        Statement stmt=connection.createStatement();
        String querystring="select loc from location";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(querystring );
        while(rs.next())  {
        Element child1 = doc.createElement("company");
        child1.setAttributeNS(comp,"comp:loc", rs.getString (1));
```